# Record User Actions in Android

Tags: android, action

Is there any way to record user actions in android. Like if someone clicks a button or enters a text, how to identify those actions. Is this possible in an emulator atleast. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Ravi,I want the same thing what you have asked.did you get the solution for question?

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 3):

Every view has its event listeners. You can browse the documentation and find which listeners are supported by every view. For example, you can register `onClickListener` on your view, then you will receive the event and you can process it. You should check the documentation at developer.android.com to get more info. Good luck!

Comment: i want to record the user interactions in another app and save it. In that case can i use these event listeners.?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you want to do exactly. You could override the onUserInteraction() of an activity, wich is fired every time the user interacts with that activity.
If you want a more specific logging you will need to create custom buttons (extending the normal button and add some functionality) that sends the logging data to a central point for logging.

Comment: My aim is to record the UIEvents from an android emulator. To capture the button clicks, text enterd, etc. How to acheive that? And that too no specific to any application.

Comment: You want to make an android keylogger for other applications? Asside from the ethical implications of that I would have no idea how to do that.